# Firefox addon development - tabs api - blacklist url patterns from inject the exstension code (like in chrome)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons

I am using the addons sdk/tabs api to inject content scripts into tabs when they are loaded like this:

```
tabs.on(ready, function (tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    contentScriptFile: myAwesomeArrayOfScripts
  });

  ...
```

Is there an easy way i can prevent the attach on domain patterns?
Most importantly i need to prevent it to work on about: domains like the new tab page of firefox.

Obviously i'm able to control execution with code like this:

```
if (tab.url.indexOf('about:') === 0) return;
```

But it looks very unclear solution compared to chrome declarative manifest, where you can have this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*" ],
```

Is there anything similar? Firefox documentation is confusing... too many things and too many versions and articles from the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`sdk/page-mod` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) instead of attaching  content scripts via tabs events if you want to declare a content script. Then you can use the `include`and `exclude` keys to specify URL patterns (`exclude` was introduced in Firefox 32).

Using Firefox's `tab.attach` is similar to [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), which should only be used to imperatively execute a content script.

Comment: Sorry, for the late approval of the response, i've been away from this project for while.
When using the page-mod to inject scripts, can i still use port.emit and port.on like i do with the tabs api?

Comment: @paolo.caminiti Yes. Use the `onAttach` event to get a `worker`, then communicate with the tab's content script using `worker.port`. For an example, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts